# Data Directory in File Explorer of DDMS View

Tags: android

Hi all using Samsung Galaxy GT-1900 ,In eclipse I am trying to access data folder in DDMS file explorer view of my application,its data folder visible but unable to open,facing same problem as posted here [Can't access data folder in the File Explorer of DDMS using a Nexus One!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259380/cant-access-data-folder-in-the-file-explorer-of-ddms-using-a-nexus-one.As) I click plus on data folder if disappear for 2-6.I try to explore data folder with normal and also with debug mode.still unable to access this folder.when I run my application on emulator its working fine in emulator I can visit data folder in DDMS file explorer view.Any suited answer how I can access this folder to export/explore my database and txt files.Below I am attaching my DDMS view ..
[image: Android DDMS File Explorer View in eclipse]

Answer (score 8):

On **rooted** device you can do this:

1. Open cmd
2. Type '`adb shell`'
3. `su`
4. Press 'Allow' on device
5. `chmod 777 /data /data/data /data/data/com.application.pacakage`
6. Go to the DDMS view in Eclipse

After this you should be able to browse the files on the device.

Comment: its worked for me when i was trying above steps, thought chmod command  didn't executed successfully :D

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, you need to root your phone to get access to `/data`, it's forbidden due to rights management, by default.